# Perl, Inline_Java, Java dynamic load of object and method

Tags: java, perl, inline-code

Can anyone assist me on how do I load the object FooBar dynamically and call the roquet function (dynamically) ? 
I have this snippet in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use Inline Java => << 'End_Of_Java_Code';
class FooBar {
  public FooBar(){}
    public void roquet() {
        System.out.println("HELLO!");
    }
}
End_Of_Java_Code

use Data::Dumper;
use Class::Sniff;
my $sniff = Class::Sniff->new({class=>'FooBar'});
my $num_methods = $sniff->methods;
my $num_classes = $sniff->classes;
my @methods     = $sniff->methods;
my @classes     = $sniff->classes;

my @unreachable = $sniff->unreachable;
foreach my $method (@methods) {
  if ( $method eq "roquet" ) {
    print "$method\n";
  }
}
```

**I tried the following approaches and variations:**
a. approach:

```
use Module::Load
my $package = "main::FooBar";
load $package;
$package->new();
$package->$rflmethod;//where rflmethod is the variable: $rflmethod='roquet';
```

b. approach:

```
no strict 'refs';
use Package::Stash;
my $stash = Package::Stash->new('main::FooBar');
my $coderef = $stash->get_symbol('&__new');
$coderef->()
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
my ($class, $method) = qw(FooBar roquet);
my $f = $class->new;
$f->$method;
```